# Weird flash, .html .htm and /home.html - how to change the htaccess file and configuration for site's home

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am looking at a friend's site which was built like 5+ years ago and its really antiquated. The url is http://www.crystalvine.com

The structure of the site is that there is a index.htmh and a http://www.crystalvine.com/home.html

What I want to do is place a 301 redirect from the /home.html to index.html

and move the code from the home.html to index.html

I tried to do this:

```
# THE TWO LINES BELOW WERE ADDED BY WEB.COM SO THAT YOUR SITE USES PHP4 INSTEAD OF PHP5
AddHandler php4-script .php
Action php4-script /system-cgi/php4

Redirect 301 /home.html http://www.crystalvine.com/index.html
```

But it isn't working as I thought it would, for some reason.

What would be the 301 redirect to do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
Redirect 301 /home\.html http://www.crystalvine.com/index.html
```

or  try the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home\.html$ http://www.crystalvine.com/index.html [NC,L,R=301]
```